# Python - Match substring occurrences between { } with regex

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I'm trying to search for one or more occurrences of a variable substring between two selectors "{" and "}" using regex. If it finds more than one, the output should be a list.

Here is an example of string :

```
mystring = "foofoofoo{something}{anything}foofoofoo"
```

This is the regex I use :

```
re.findall(r"^.*(\{.*\}).*$", mystring)
```

but it gives me the following output : `{anything}`

I've tried with `r"(\{.*\})"` and it returns me `{something}{anything}` which is almost good except it's not a list.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove anchors and `.*` from your regex to allow it to just capture from `{` to `}`:

```
>>> mystring = "foofoofoo{something}{anything}foofoofoo";
>>> re.findall(r"(\{[^}]*\})", mystring);
['{something}', '{anything}']
```

To skip `{` and `}` from matches, use captured groups:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\{([^}]*)\}", mystring);
['something', 'anything']
```

Comment: No need for lookarounds, simply capture the content: `{(.*?)}`

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(r"({.*?})", mystring)
```

Make your `*` non greedy.